# Java Bytecode: Customized setter/getter with byte buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, byte-buddy

I am trying to create a "custom" setter method for a field with byte buddy.
Buddy's own mechanism allows for standard setter/getter methods to be implemented very easily, however, I am looking for an elegant way to extend the setter with some additional logic.

To simplify the example, let's assume we have a class A, which has a method setChanged(String).
Goal is to make a sub-class of A, add a field with corresponding access methods.
The catch is, that I want to call setChanged("fieldName") from each added setter method.

```
public void setName(String name)
{
  setChanged("name");
  this.name = name;
}
```

For a "normal" setter method, byte byddy implementation would be:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(A.class)
  .name("B")
  .defineField("name", Integer.TYPE, Visibility.PUBLIC)
   // args is a ArrayList<Class<?>>
  .defineMethod(getSetterName(name), Void.TYPE, args, Visibility.PUBLIC) 
  .intercept( FieldAccessor.ofField(name) )
```

Bytecode I am after looks like this:

```
L0
 ALOAD 0       // Loads the this reference onto the operand stack
 ILOAD 1       // Loads the integer value of the local variable 1 (first method arg)
 PUTFIELD package/B.name : I // stores the value to the field
L1
 ALOAD 0
 LDC "name"
 INVOKEVIRTUAL package/A.setChanged (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 RETURN
```

My question is: is there a way to re-use FieldAccessor in this context?

Comment: I’m not sure what’s your actual question. Do you want to know whether you can store the result of `FieldAccessor.ofField(…)` into a variable and use it multiple times? Why don’t you try it? Or what kind of re-use do you mean?

Comment: Hi Holger,
I would like to extend the FieldAccessor.ofField(...) with a method call (in the example above: setChanged("name");). 
I meant re-use of code, not objects. Basically (this may be misinformed approach), I would like to get the stack manipulation of the FieldAccessor and use it in another compound stack manipulation.

Comment: Well, there’s [`Instrumentation.Compound`](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/0.3.1/net/bytebuddy/instrumentation/Instrumentation.Compound.html#Compound-net.bytebuddy.instrumentation.Instrumentation...-), but strangely, I didn’t find any way to call another method on `this`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, you would need to define a custom `Instrumentation` to do such a custom job. As pointed out in the comments, you can then use an `Instrumentation.Compound` to prepend the new behavior to for example `FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty()` and thus reuse the field accessor code.

In order to add custom code, Byte Buddy knows different abstraction levels:

1. `Instrumentation`: Defines how a method is implemented. An instrumentation is able to define additional fields, methods or static initializer blocks that are required to implement a method. Furthermore, it determines if a method is to be defined for a type at all.
2. A `ByteCodeAppender` is emitted by an `Instrumentation` and determines if a defined method is abstract and a method's byte code if a method is implemented.
3. A `StackManipulation` is a byte code instruction with a given impact on an operand stack's size. Stack manipulations are composed for implementing a non-abstract method.

In order to call a method in byte code, you need to load all arguments (including `this`) onto the stack and call the method after placing all these arguments. This can be done as follows:

1. Load the `this` reference onto the stack by `MethodVariableAccess.REFERENCE.loadFromIndex(0)`.
2. Load a string onto the stack that describes the field that is access. This can be derived from the method's name which is given to a `ByteCodeAppender` as an argument. Using a `TextConstant`, a name can then be placed on the stack.
3. A method can then be invoked by using a `MethodInvocation` where the `setChanged` method can be extracted from the created *instrumented type*'s `TypeDescription` which is given to the `Instrumentation` as an argument.

Of course, this is not very pretty and it is Byte Buddy's aspiration to hide this byte code level API from a user and to express anything in a DSL or in plain Java. You might therefore be happy to hear that I am currently working with Byte Buddy version 0.4 which comes with some features that you can use for this. For your example, you can implement the custom setter using an extended form of Byte Buddy's Swiss army knife, the `MethodDelegation`. A method delegation allows you to implement a method by delegating a call to any Java method using annotations.

Assuming that your beans implement a type:

```
interface Changeable {
  void setChanged(String field);
}
```

you can intercept a method call using:

```
class Interceptor {
  static void intercept(@This Changeable thiz, @Origin Method method) {
    thiz.setChanged(method.getName());
  }
}
```

Using a method delegation, Byte Buddy will always call the interceptor when a method is invoked. The interceptor method is passed arguments that describe the context of a specific interception. Above, the `this` reference and the method that is intercepted are passed.

Of course we are still missing the actual setting of the field. However, with Byte Buddy 0.4, you can now create a new `Instrumentation` as easy as follows:

```
MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class).andThen(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
```

With this delegation, Byte Buddy first calls the intercepor (then drops any potential return value) and finally applies the `Instrumentation` that is passed as an argument to the `andThen` method.

Comment: Great! That is a very helpful feature addition!
It would be great if you could give some resulting bytecode examples in the documentation (for various Byte Buddy "patterns"), to make performance assessment easier. This is a spoiled suggestion, since I could look myself, but it could help with design decisions in performance-critical cases.

Comment: I wrote an extensive tutorial but I plan a series of blog postings after release of version 0.5 which allows for a DSL creation if Java agents. Currently, I present Byte Buddy on conferences what takes a lot of time but expect such a series early next year. So long, thanks for being an early adopter.

Comment: I have read the tutorial, good work! There are of course some improvement ideas, but all in all, I find it a well written tutorial. Thanks for your efforts, keep it up! :)

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to find the tutorial at https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/gh-pages and suggest improvements by a pull request, I would be very grateful for your input as I read it with the blind eyes of a library's author.