# Byte Buddy - Method Implementation.Context.Default is no bean property - creating a setter

Tags: java, code-generation, byte-buddy

How do I create a setter on a field using byte buddy? What is the recommended syntax?

I managed to create the getter from a field (my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692972/byte-buddy-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-what-is-the-correct-definemethod)), but using the `defineMethod` to create a setter is throwing a `Method Implementation.Context.Default` ...  `is no bean property` exception.

The suggested way to create a setter in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627981/java-bytecode-customized-setter-getter-with-byte-buddy) question seems to be outdated.

Here is my failing code using version 1.5.4 of byte-buddy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Object.class)
                .name("domain")
                .defineField("id", int.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)               
                .defineMethod("getId", int.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())
                .defineMethod("setId", Void.TYPE, Visibility.PUBLIC).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty())              
                .make()
                .load(sample.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();

        Object o = type.newInstance();
        Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(o.toString());       
        Method m = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getId");
        System.out.println(m.getName());
        Method s = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setId", int.class);
        System.out.println(s.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined a parameter for the setter. Byte Buddy does therefore not understand how to implement the method. You need to set withParameters(int.class) when defining the setId method.